# How to resolve these artifact looking after apply normal map?

Tags: materials, texture-baking, normal-map

There are so many black areas showed up after the normal map connected. Thanks for answering my question. :D

[image]

I guess this image representing problems better.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the file?

Comment: There is trouble to upload the file. I uploaded a screenshot, I guess that's the problem? Maybe? It is in the original post. It looks like there is missing information from baking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. It is caused by the missing info from the normal map.
To fix the normal map, I used Photoshop to clean those spots, and it works just fine without baking another one.

[image]